# System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Mailbox unavailable

Tags: c#, smtp, exchange-server

```
// CREATE NEW EMAIL OBJECT
ContactUs.Core.Email oEmail = new ContactUs.Core.Email();

// EMAIL SMTP SERVER INFORMATION
oEmail.SmtpServer = "Server";
oEmail.SetAuthentication("Email", "Password");

// EMAIL INFORMATION
oEmail.From = "contact@Server.com";
oEmail.To = "RecipientEmail";
oEmail.Subject = this.txtMessage.Text;
oEmail.Message = strMessage;

// SEND EMAIL
oEmail.HtmlFormat = true;
oEmail.Send();
```

This is the error I am getting. I know that the authentication is correct.

```
System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.1 Client does not have permissions to send as this sender
at System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.CheckResponse(SmtpStatusCode statusCode, String response)
at System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.Send(SmtpConnection conn, Byte[] command, String from)
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.SendMail(MailAddress sender, MailAddressCollection recipients, String deliveryNotify, SmtpFailedRecipientException& exception)
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
at ContactUs.Core.Email.Send()
at _Default.btnSend_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Answer (score 2):

5.7.1 == relaying prohibited

You need to allow relaying for authenticated users, or from a range of IPs from your SMTP server: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304897

What kind of server are you using to relay the messages?

Comment: MX 2007. I just changed the recipient to an internal domain & now I am getting a server error in application.

Comment: what's MX 2007, who makes it, link to the website?  

Do you have the ability to change the settings on that server?

Comment: If it's Exchange 2007 here are the instructions to allow relaying http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2006/12/28/3397620.aspx

Comment: Every email i am using is from the same domain. Why would I need to turn on relaying?

Comment: It's still relaying, even if you're sending to your own domain. This is really a server configuration question as you are able to contact the SMTP server just fine, it's just giving you back an unable to relay message. The article in my comment above explains the changes required to allow relaying. Try using a mail client (like Outlook, or Thunderbird) to send out using this SMTP server, you should get the same 5.7.1 error.

Answer (score 1):

you have to set username in the SMTP Authentication as **contact@Server.com**.

```
        // CREATE NEW EMAIL OBJECT
        ContactUs.Core.Email oEmail = new ContactUs.Core.Email();

        // EMAIL SMTP SERVER INFORMATION
        oEmail.SmtpServer = "Server";
        oEmail.SetAuthentication("contact@Server.com", "Password");

        // EMAIL INFORMATION
        oEmail.From = "contact@Server.com";
        oEmail.To = "RecipientEmail";
        oEmail.Subject = this.txtMessage.Text;
        oEmail.Message = strMessage;

        // SEND EMAIL
        oEmail.HtmlFormat = true;
        oEmail.Send();
```

Your SMTP Server doesn't allow you to set Credential username different from oEmail.From (e-mail address of Sender).

Answer (score 0):

Add Network credentials to your code.

Sample Mail Code:

```
private void SendMailViaGmailUsingCredentials()
        {
            try
            {
                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");

                mail.From = new MailAddress("your_email_address@gmail.com");
                mail.To.Add("to_address@mfc.ae");
                mail.Subject = "Test Mail";
                mail.Body = "This is for testing SMTP mail from GMAIL";

                SmtpServer.Port = 587;
                SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
                SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

                SmtpServer.Send(mail);
                MessageBox.Show("mail Send");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
}
```